# Read MATLAB dataset without headers

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a MATLAB dataset and I want to extract the numbers only without reading the headers. Is there any straightforward way to do that?

I HAVE THIS:

```
                                      MeanOfTrainingMSE    MeanOfTestMSE
Naive Regression                          26.291            26.327      
Linear Regression (attribute 400)         1.2466            1.2592      
Linear Regression (attribute 357)          1.214            1.2356      
Linear Regression (attribute 440)         1.1494            1.1562      
Linear Regression (attribute 404)         1.0072            1.0111      
Linear Regression (attribute 238)        0.92402           0.93002      
Linear Regression (attribute 473)        0.89838           0.90397      
Linear Regression (all attributes)    4.1155e-07            877.58      
Ridge Regression                      2.9044e-10            0.2533      
Kernel Ridge Regression                   1054.8            1023.2
```

I WANT TO GET THIS:

```
26.291            26.327
1.2466            1.2592
1.214             1.2356
1.1494            1.1562
1.0072            1.0111
0.92402           0.93002
0.89838           0.90397
4.1155e-07        877.58
2.9044e-10        0.2533
1054.8            1023.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataset is named `aFile`, for example, you can retrieve the values of those columns of interest by

```
>> X=[aFile.MeanOfTrainingMSE aFile.MeanOfTestMSE]
```

Edit to answer your comment:

There may be a better way, but you could do something like:

```
>> m=length(aFile.Properties.ObsNames);
>> n=length(aFile.Properties.VarNames);
>> data=ones(m,n);
>> names=aFile.Properties.VarNames; 
>> for a =1:n
     data(:,a)=aFile.(names{a});
   end
```

Of course this assumes each column in your data is numeric.

Comment: Thank you! And what if we have hundred of columns?